# Returning function result into array

Tags: php, arrays

I am passing an array to a function and expecting the function to store values in it. Here's my code

**The Function** -

```
    function GetDetailsById ($iStudentId, $aDetailsId)
    {
        /* SQL */

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
           array_push($aDetailsId, $row[0]);
        }
    }
```

**Usage** -

```
    $aDetailsId = array();
    $oDetailsTable->GetDetailsById("1", $aDetailsId)
```

When I try to do

```
print_r($aDetailsId)
```

the array shows nothing. Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: isn't it typo :  `array_push($aDetailsId), $row[0]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array needs to be passed by reference to the function ; which means the function should be defined this way :

```
function GetDetailsById ($iStudentId, & $aDetailsId)
{
  // ...
}
```

For more informations, see [**Making arguments be passed by reference**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.by-reference)

Or you could have your function [**return its result**][2] -- which might be better idea *(looking at the code that calls the function, you immediately know what it does)* :

```
function GetDetailsById ($iStudentId)
{
    $result = array();
    // TODO here, fill $result with your data
    return $result;
}
```

And call the function :

```
$aDetailsId = $oDetailsTable->GetDetailsById("1");
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because parameters are passed *by value* by default, meaning only the value of the variable is passed into the function, not the variable itself. Whatever you do to the value inside the function does not affect the original outside the function.

Two options:

1. `return` the modified value from the function.
2. [Pass the parameter by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.by-reference):

   ```
   function GetDetailsById ($iStudentId, &$aDetailsId) ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

first count/check your `resutl` is contain any resultset. and try using '&' in parameter of array

```
function GetDetailsById ($iStudentId, &$aDetailsId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change function declaration to,

```
function GetDetailsById ($iStudentId, &$aDetailsId)
```

There is one more mistake in `array_push` call. Change it to,

```
array_push($aDetailsId, $row[0]);
```